# Word for sabot-like component in a non-projectile apparatus?

Tags: single-word-requests

A sabot, in the context of weapon design, is a smooth covering that allows an irregularly shaped projectile to fit snugly in a tubular bore. A similar design can be used to securely mount a small-diameter cylinder within a tube that would otherwise be too large for it. Sabot seems to reside exclusively in the context of projectile weapons, but what would a more appropriate word be to describe this general structure? Specifically, picture a thick walled tube (the "sabot") which has an outer diameter just large enough to fit securely in an outer tube and an inner diameter just large enough to accept a narrower cylinder, such that the "sabot" allows the narrow cylinder to be mounted in the center of the larger outer tube.

Ex: We machined a ___ with which to consistently position the rod within the containment tube.

Comment: *adapter tube, centering jig/fixture, locating tube*.  Maybe it’s just a ***sleeve***

Comment: @Jim adaptor is certainly a good word for this that I hadn't thought of. However, I'm still interested to see if anyone digs up something more specific.

Comment: Or maybe it’s a ***casing***

Comment: or it could be called a _housing_

Comment: As long as it's relatively thin and doesn't have a structural role, you can call it a shim tube. Common ones are used to match a bicycle seat post to a bike frame's seat tube. Shims generally get squeezed between two other objects.

Answer (score 1):

**Sleeve**

> sleeve
>   noun
>   1. the part of a garment that covers the arm, varying in form and length but commonly tubular.
>   2. an envelope, usually of paper, for protecting a phonograph record.
>   **3. *Machinery.* a tubular piece, as of metal, fitting over a rod or the like.**
>   
>   verb (used with object), sleeved, sleeving.
>   4. to furnish with sleeves.
>   **5. *Machinery.* to fit with a sleeve; join or fasten by means of a sleeve.**
>   
>   [[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sleeve)]

Comment: That's what I've come across in engineering use (UK)